# Python - Printing only once from a nested loop

Tags: python, excel, nested-loops, xlwt

I have an excel file that looks like this:

```
      col1     col2    col3    col4
      -----------------------------
row1 | 2,3,1    _        1      w
row2 | 3,2,7    _        2      x
row3 |   _      _        3      y
row4 |  4,9     _        4      z
```

I'm writing some values (using XLWT) in column 2 that look like this:

```
      col1     col2    col3    col4
      -----------------------------
row1 | 2,3,1  x,y,w      1      w
row2 | 3,2,7   y,x       2      x
row3 |   _      _        3      y
row4 |  4,9     z        4      z
```

My problem is that my code is iterating the right values in the right place, but too many times (as a result of nested loops I'm thinking).

Here's the most important part of the code (the fluff has been cut out).

```
def question():
    newtprint = set() #set I created outside of loops to call later one, supposed to prevent repeated iterations from nested loops
    for x in xrange(sheet.nrows): #iterates over all rows
        for i in xrange(len(newton)): #col1
            for n in xrange(len(james)): #col2
                if newton[i] == james[n]:
                    newtprint.add(path[n]) #adds specified col4 value into set
        print newtprint, x #writes current set being written and row it's written into
        sheety.write(x, 1, str(newtprint)) #writes into col2 based on col4 sets
        wb.save('C:/.../names.xls')
```

I had help with this earlier, and I thought it worked, but I guess it didn't function like I originally believed: [Dealing with Nested Loops in Python - Options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33878986/dealing-with-nested-loops-in-python-options)

Just looking for options to prevent constant iteration. Here's what's appearing in my cmd: [image: http://i.imgur.com/VFkDVxw.png]

The red bracket shows the first set of values being printed normally, then it starts printing those same values over and over again for a small period of time before going to the next set of values and repeatedly printing those.

Comment: which part of the bracketed screenshot is "normal", because it all looks the same to me.

Comment: I have the row values printed at the end. The first row value "22" is correct (top part of bracket), the rest are repetitions of 22.

Comment: Indentation matters in python. Your `print` and `sheety.write` statements are repeated for each row, so it's printing `newtprint, x ` even if your conditional is not met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would make more sense:

```
def question():
    for x in xrange(sheet.nrows): #iterates over all rows
        newtprint = set()
        for i in xrange(len(newton)): #col1
            for n in xrange(len(james)): #col2
                if newton[i] == james[n]:
                    newtprint.add(path[n]) #adds specified col4 value into set
        print newtprint, x #writes current set being written and row it's written into
        sheety.write(x, 1, str(newtprint)) #writes into col2 based on col4 sets
        wb.save('C:/.../names.xls')
```

You write `newtprint` for every row into the new file. Therefore, you should make a new set for each row.

Comment: Thank you so much, haha. I can't believe the answer was that simple. This worked perfectly!

Comment: Often the answer is simple but finding it can be difficult.